# Is it possible to do an Between two varchar values

Tags: php, mysqli

Kund = customer
We know that we lack in security in our code but so far that is not the problem and this code will not go on to an public website.

This code sorts out values from an database and puts them in a table.
We need to sort the customer S001 and everything between to S176 in a checkbox but we cant get BETWEEN to work with Varchar.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">

</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "garp";

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

/*                                                                                                                                      $query = $_GET['query']; */
$orderkund = $_GET['Orderkundinput']; 
$artikel = $_GET['Artikelinput']; 
$startDate =$_GET['startDate']; 
$endDate =$_GET['endDate'] ;
$kund =$_GET['kund'];
$kund2 =$_GET['kund2'];
$kunds;

$min_length = 0;
$artikelQuery="";
$orderkundQuery="";
$kundQuery="";
$kund2Query="";
$kundsQuery;
if(strlen($artikel) >= $min_length){ 
    $artikel = htmlspecialchars($artikel); 

    $artikel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $artikel);
    $artikelQuery = " AND Artikelnr = '$artikel'";
}

if (strlen($orderkund) >= $min_length){ 
    $orderkund = htmlspecialchars($orderkund); 

    $orderkund = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $orderkund);
    $orderkundQuery = " AND OrderKund = '$orderkund'";
}
if(strlen($kund) >= $min_length){ 
    $kund = htmlspecialchars($kund); 

    $kund = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $kund);
    $kundQuery = " OR OrderKund = '$kund'";
}
if(strlen($kund2) >= $min_length){ 
    $kund2 = htmlspecialchars($kund2); 

    $kund2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $kund2);
    $kund2Query = " OR OrderKund = '$kund2'";
}
if(strlen($kunds) >= $min_length){ 
    $kunds = htmlspecialchars($kunds); 

    $kunds = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $kunds);
    $kundsQuery = " between 'S176'";
}
if (strlen($startDate) >= $min_length){ 
    $startDate = htmlspecialchars($startDate); 

    $startDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $startDate);
    $startDateQuery = " AND Orderdatum between '$startDate' ";
}

if (strlen($endDate) >= $min_length){ 
    $endDate = htmlspecialchars($endDate); 

    $endDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $endDate);
    $endDateQuery = "AND '$endDate'";
}

$query = $artikelQuery.$orderkundQuery.$kundQuery.$kund2Query.$kundsQuery.$startDateQuery.$endDateQuery;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
$sql = "SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,OrderKund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where  OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K'" .$query ;
echo $sql;
$raw_results = $conn->query ($sql);
    $row_cnt = false === $raw_results ? 0 : $raw_results->num_rows;
        echo " <p class='rows'> Numbers of rows loaded: $row_cnt </p>";
    if($row_cnt > 0){
   while($raw_result = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
   echo "<table class='table'><thead class='thead-light'><tr><th class='col'>".'Ordernummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'OrderserieIK'."</th><th class='col'>".'Orderkund'."</th><th class='col'>".'fakturakund'."</th><th class='col'>".'orderdatum'."</th><th class='col'>".'erreferens'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveratvarde'."</th><th class='col'>".'radnummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'artikelnr'."</th><th class='col'>".'benamning'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveranstid'."</th><th class='col'>".'Ursprungligtantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'Levereratantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'forspris'."</th><th class='col'>".'bruttopris'."</th><th class='col'>".'varukostnad'."</th></tr></thead>";
   echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$raw_result['Ordernummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['OrderserieIK']."</td><td>".$raw_result['OrderKund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Fakturakund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Orderdatum']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Erreferens']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratvarde']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Radnummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Artikelnr']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Benamning']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Leveranstid']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Ursprungligtantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Forspris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Bruttopris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Varukostnad']."</td></tr></tbody></table>";

   }
    }

    else{
   echo "No return";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
$query = substr($query, 4);
$sql2 = "SELECT OrderKund,Artikelnr, SUM(Forspris) as Forspris,SUM(Levereratantal) as Levereratantal FROM orderhuvud
left JOIN orderrad on orderhuvud.Ordernummer = orderrad.Ordernummer
 where ". $query ." GROUP BY OrderKund,Artikelnr";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<div class='continer'><table class='table'><thead class='thead-light'><tr><th class='col'>".'OrderKund'."</th><th class='col'>".'Artikelnr'."</th><th class='col'>".'Forspris'."</th><th class='col'>".'levereratantal'."</th></tr></thead></div>";
    echo "<div class='continer'><tbody><tr><td>".$row['OrderKund']."</td><td>".$row['Artikelnr']."</td><td>".$row['Forspris']."</td><td>".$row['Levereratantal']."</td></tr></tbody></table></div>";   
}
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us the query that is being executed? var_dump($sql); before $raw_results = $con...

Comment: Yes we know but so far it is just an exampel to try to make it work. we are doing this as an school internship and we just started studying this type of coding.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca OP's first sentence states that he know this lacks in security and that this code never will be on a public website.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen heh, missed the first line completely...

Comment: @AndrewLarsen string(493) "SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,OrderKund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K' AND Artikelnr = '' AND OrderKund = 's1' OR OrderKund = '' OR OrderKund = 'S001' between 'S176' AND Orderdatum between '' AND ''" this is what we got

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this part is responsible for not giving the rows you expect.

```
OR orderkund = 'S001' BETWEEN 'S176' AND orderdatum BETWEEN '' AND ''
```

First of all, I would remove the last part since it's empty strings on each side and it doesn't really do anything.

```
orderdatum BETWEEN '' AND ''
```

I have never used the between function before, but from what I see it seems like you shouldn't have the equal comparison before the between. I would also suggest to wrap the specific between condition within parantheses so we're sure the conditions aren't mixed with eachother, so the end-result should look something like this:

```
OR (orderkund BETWEEN 'S001' AND 'S176') AND (orderdatum BETWEEN '' AND '')
```

As mentioned above, I would suggest you to remove the last part if orderdatum value is not available.

Comment: The orderdatum part is somthing that you type in a input. so it's only empty if i dont chose a value. But i can try to se what happens if put in the parantheses and update whit an beter query

Comment: This is the new SQL code whit all the values SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,OrderKund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K' AND Artikelnr = '15' AND OrderKund = 'S115' OR OrderKund = '16' OR (OrderKund = 'S001' between 'S176') AND (Orderdatum between '2015-04-16' AND '2017-04-04')"

Comment: You should remove the equal symbol as mentioned above. And you have to add AND between the values. And you should have BETWEEN before the first value. So instead of it looking like this: OR (OrderKund = 'S001' between 'S176') it should look like this: OR (OrderKund BETWEEN 'S001' AND 'S176')

Comment: We did the changes but it only shows up to S019. It's still beter then nothing is there anything more that comes to your mind? We trid the SQL code in phpMyAdmin and it worked there

Comment: Would try Sayed Mohd Ali's answer below, think you have to substring to achieve the result you want. In the future I would suggest keeping fields like this numeric as long as it's possible. I giess that "orderkund" is either customer id or order id, and it would be easier to work with if it were a integer.

Comment: I tride it but i think somthing went wrong but i am wating for an answer from him but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  column_name from table_name  where SUBSTRING(`customer`, 2)  between 001 and 176
```

This is working I already tried it on MySQL

```
select OrderKund from orderhuvud where SUBSTRING(OrderKund, 2) between 1 and 176
```

Comment: I think i did somthing wrong when trying to use it because i got all of the results from OrderKund so it was not just the S001 - S176 but all of them. Here is What it locked like: select `OrderKund` from orderhuvud where SUBSTRING(`OrderKund`, 2) between 001 and 176

Comment: @D24kölagöt and it dosn't matter either you write 001, 00001, 0000001 or 1. talking about between part it will always take 1

Comment: I got it to work almost but now i get S001 - S019 this how it locks: WHERE SUBSTRING(`OrderKund`, 2) between 'S001' and 'S176'

Comment: don't use S & ''
just write 1 and 176...
WHERE SUBSTRING(OrderKund, 2) between 1 and 176

Comment: you can also create table demo here and share the link with me...
 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1

Comment: I dont understand how that website works. Can you explain?

Comment: on this website, you can create a table and insert data into it. then you can easily share the link to anyone and they can write a query for it.

Comment: if you want to test any query, run that query directly into your database instead of your php code. because in php code other php errors can conflict your result.